# My mic is not working although it seems to have a controller

Tags: sound

I just downloaded Ubuntu (less than 10 days ago). I just tried to use the microphone, but it doesn't work.

It says I do have a controller, but no audio gets into the computer. The out works well.

[image: Picture of my audio settings]

Right now I tried with some wireless headphones, but they don't work either.

I tried with some weird commands from a YouTube video. But didn't work.

```
Command: sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
options snd-hda-intel model=,dell-headset-multi
```

---

EDIT
I used the alsamixer command, which @petep recommended, and this was the output. I think this could be the problem.

The image says "This sound device has no capture controllers"

Please tell me if this is the problem :D

[image]

Comment: try unmute mic with ``alsamixer'' command

Comment: @petep i just made an edit. please check it. I think that could be the problem

Comment: change to mic rec card with F6